# Where is the readline function located in C?

Tags: c, readline

In an assignment for college it was suggested to use the C `readline` function in an exercise. I have searched for its reference but still haven't found it. Does it really exist? In which header? Can you please post the link to the reference?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Readline exists in two places, `libreadline` and `libedit` (also called `libeditline`). Both have an identical interface. The difference is libreadline is licensed under the GPL, libedit is 3 clause BSD. Licensing is really not a concern for an assignment, at least I don't think it is. Either license allows you to use the code freely. If you link against readline, be sure to make the whole program `GPL 2 or later` which will satisfy whatever version of the GPL governs the system `readline`. It may be GPL2+ or GPL3+, depending on the age of the system. I'm not advocating either license, that's up to you.

Note, take care to install either / or and adjust linking as needed (`-lreadline` *or* `-ledit` *or* `-leditline`). Both are libraries and not a part of the standard C library.

**Edit** (afterthought):

If releasing a program to the wild, its a nice gesture to allow the user to configure it with their `readline` of choice. For instance: `--with-readline` or `--with-libedit`, etc. This allows a binary package that conforms to their choice of license, at least as far as `readline` is concerned.

Links: [Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) and [Edit/Editline](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/).

Comment: Yes, I have seen `libedit` incarnate as `libeditline` on more than a few systems, though I can't remember what they were at the moment.

Comment: Also note, I did not link to either license. readline can be GPL2-or-later or GPL3 depending on the version you use, however the 3 clause BSD license remains static.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a standard function.

I simple implementation would be like this:

```
char *Readline(char *in) {
   char *cptr;

   if (cptr = fgets(in, MAX_LINE, stdin)) {
     /* kill preceding whitespace but leave \n so we're guaranteed to have something
     while(*cptr == ' ' || *cptr == '\t') {
       cptr++;
     }
     return cptr;    
    } else {
     return 0;
   }
 }
```

It uses fgets() to read up to MAX_LINE - 1 characters into the buffer 'in'. It strips preceding whitespace and returns a pointer to the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: readline() offers a command history, tab completion, simple line editing,, etc. Its an external but wildly popular library.

Comment: @Tim: You're right, the Readline library does that, but I think he only wants a function to read a line as a C char array.

Comment: I think he wanted links to the libraries.

Comment: Maybe he meant getline?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you tried reading this from the GNU C Library: `ssize_t getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)`.
This function reads a line from a file and can even re-allocate more space if needed.

An example of this is found in the manpage of getline. Below is a copy of it.

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       FILE *stream;
       char *line = NULL;
       size_t len = 0;
       ssize_t nread;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
       if (stream == NULL) {
           perror("fopen");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
           printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", nread);
           fwrite(line, nread, 1, stdout);
       }

       free(line);
       fclose(stream);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Comment: Please do not attach link of the entire documentation, instead link related parts and try to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a "readLine()" function, like the readLine() in Java-BufferedReader, you can also freely use my function «char* get_line(FILE *filePointer)» in "line.h", which I wrote just for this purpose: https://github.com/pheek/line.h/blob/master/line.h

Answer (score -6):

It doesn't exist.

They were mistaken and referred to gets() from stdio.h.

Also this is a very unsafe function due to no maximum size to read parameter, making it immediate security whole (lookup buffer overrun attack). You may use fgets() instead.

Comment: No, **don't** use `gets` -- ever!

Comment: @Jerry +1... do you recommend using fgets ?

Comment: To back Jerry up: `gets` doesn't let you specify a limit on the number of characters to read. This is bad, because you're reading into a character array, which has a fixed length. If you read text that's longer than the length of the array, you get a buffer overflow, which could result in your program crashing or memory that's not supposed to be touched being overwritten.

Comment: Yes, `fgets` is fine, if a bit of a pain. It normally leaves the '\n' on the end of the string. An easy (though odd) way to strip that off is `strtok(string, "\n");`.

Comment: Or: if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] == '\n') buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';

Comment: It most decidedly _does_ exist, in fact two libraries offering the same API under different licenses are available to implement it. It offers neat stuff like command line editing, tab completion, history, etc ... , kind of essential for any CLI.