# Scanf for a two strings and a float number

Tags: c, scanf

I am creating a menu that needs to take in an three inputs from the users.

```
    char *fullname;
    char *date;
    float sal;
    printf("\nEnter full name: ");
```

line92

```
scanf("%s", &fullname);
printf("\nEnter hire date: ");
```

Line 94

```
scanf("%s", &date);
printf("\nEnter salary: ");
```

Line 96

```
scanf("%d", &sal);
```

These are the errors I am recieving

```
Employee.c:92: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
Employee.c:94: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’
Employee.c:96: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’
```

Can I get an explanation of what is causing these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

First:

When you use `scanf` for strings you do not use the `&`. So just `scanf("%s", fullname);`.

Second:

Your pointers aren't initialized. Try this instead:

```
char fullname[256];
char date[256];
```

This will work as long as you input at most 255 characters.

Third:

Your typing for the last `scanf` doesn't match. You're passing in a `float` when you've specified an `int` in the format string. Try this:

```
scanf("%f", &sal);
```

Comment: This seems to get rid of the warnings but when you enter the code it sefaults on me

Comment: Can you trace which line it segfaults on?

Comment: Ok I figured that it segfaulted because I was doing something wrong. I want to be able to enter a full name "John Doe" but it segfault because of the space. Is there a way to input a string like this

Comment: I'm not aware of a C function that will read the whole line. See this question for that: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600528/c-readline-function)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have gone a different way

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are pretty self-explanatory. When you call `scanf` with a `%s` format specifier you need to provide it a pointer to the first element of a char array where the string can be copied to. You're not doing that, instead you're giving it the address of a pointer to a char.

```
char[100] fullname;
scanf( "%s", fullname );
```

The same problem exists for date. Also, be aware that using the code above, a buffer overflow will occur if the user enters a string equal to or more than 100 characters in length.

If you're using MSVC you can use the `scanf_s` function instead that requires you to enter the length of the buffer. However, this function is Microsoft specific, hence, non-portable.

```
scanf_s( "%s", fullname, 100 );
```

For salary, the problem is that the format specifier is `%d`, which is used for reading ints, not floats. Use

```
scanf( "%f", &sal );
```